# SQL Server Query Hints for EXISTS Clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, query-optimization

I'm trying to force SQL server to use a hash Match for exists clause as below.

[Execution Plan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mhyeq.png)

```
FROM 
    [Dbo].[360 Nrc Data] AS [nrc]
WHERE 
    [CALENDAR_DATE] BETWEEN @START_DATE AND @End_Date
    AND EXISTS (SELECT 1
                FROM [staging].[FACT_DTV_RETENTION_EVENT_STEP_1] AS [fact]
                WHERE [fact].[CD_PORTFOLIO_ID] = [nrc].[Cd_Portfolio_Id]
                  AND [fact].[Event_Date] = [nrc].[CALENDAR_DATE])
GROUP BY 
    [Calendar_Date], [Cd_Portfolio_Id])
```

The normal way to force query hint is as below but Left Semi Join is more efficient than has join

```
[_fact_date_and_portfolio] AS [fact]    
     inner hash join    

     [dbo].[360 TA Offer] AS [offr]
```

Comment: Why would you want to force a hash match?  An appropriate index would probably be faster.

Comment: doing > 10M join, I want to force is as a lot of the time SQL Server get the row estimate wrong.

Answer (score 4):

There is no hint syntax to specify the physical join type for a specific semi join or anti semi join operator.

But as this plan only has one join you can just add `OPTION (HASH JOIN)` to the end of the query. The hint applies to all joins but there aren't any others.